# how to print one attribute of many objetcs of an array without a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a snackbar, which is like a alert window and i want to list all ids of every objects that is contained in the **Array** `zugewieseneMerkmale` in it.
Hopefully you have an idea. Thanks in advance

```
this._snackBar.open( JSON.stringify(zugewieseneMerkmale)+ " ist schon zugewiesen!", "OK");
```

Comment: `zugewieseneMerkmale.map(v => v.id).join(', ')` should be what you're looking for

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept Ivan's answer below to close the question, the core concept was to just use map (and eventually join to join the array).

Answer (score 1):

You can access the property of the objects inside your array with a .map() method;

**map** basically calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array.

So you should do something like this:

```
array.map(item => item.id)
```